# Application hosting on IIS is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted a release (asp.net C#) as website is working on IIS. but same release as an application under a website is not working. It couldn't access the files.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which framework do you use, .net core or .net framework? What version of IIS server? How does it "not working"? Provide `web.confg` file.

Comment: Since your path has changed during the request process, it may be that a redirection occurred during the request process. Have you configured URL rewriting rules in IIS? I think you need to provide more detailed error page information, and you can enable FRT for your website in IIS to track error pages, and in the error log you can see more detailed reasons for the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that:

1. Grant access to the folder with your application for `IUSR`, `IIS` windows users to read (minimal)
2. Setup in `web.config` file is correct
3. Bindings configured correctly

[How to setup web.config.](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[How to grant access.](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

Any error message that you see? You must be more specific on your issue.

Comment: My IIS hosted application's page path is localhost/TestApp/Masters/AIGUser.aspx
The pages couldn't access through the TestApp path. When I click on User link, the path has changed to localhost/Masters/AIGUser.aspx, and throws as couldn't access

Comment: Have you published your site properly? You may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/